# ¿Cómo cambiar el fin de linea (LF a CRLF) en un archivo de texto plano que viene en formato Unix a Windows con Visual basic for applications?

Tags: vba, macros

Se tiene un archivo de texto plano que se descarga desde Unix, viene con el fin de línea LF y requiero convertirlo a fin de línea de windows CRLF. Pero teniendo en cuenta que no se puede recorrer registro por registro para cambiar el fin de linea.
Algo similar a un buscar y reemplazar en todo el archivo pero utilizando instrucciones Vba.

Answer (score 1):

Usando [`Scripting.FileSystemObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ar/library/aa242706(v=vs.60).aspx) para leer el archivo, luego simplemente `Replace` para modificar los fines de línea

```
Private Sub Unix2Dos(file)

    Dim fs As Object, txt As String
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    txt = fs.OpenTextFile(file, 1).ReadAll
    txt = Replace(txt, vbLf, vbCrLf)
    fs.OpenTextFile(file, 2).Write txt

End Sub
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, acabo de probar su solución y se conserva el fin de linea Inicial, al parecer no está reemplazando adecuadamente. Depronto podría orientarme con este problema? @Patricio Moracho

Comment: @DiegoAll, no hay muchas posibilidades `Replace(txt, vbLf, vbCrLf)` reemplaza el `CHAR(10)` por un `CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)`, probado. Posibilidades: que no tuvieras permiso de escritura, pero imagino que tendrías un error o que el problema en el archivo sea otro, para lo cual deberías subirlo a algún servicio tipo gdrive y compartirlo así se revisa.